# How get the name of an unknown registry key. C#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to get the name of a Registry Key and store it as a string.
I know the path that the key will be under.

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\`

The key is the Raw path for the recycling bin. The key under this path changes from computer to computer and can store more than one subkey containing the Recycle bin depending on how many users are on the installation. (From my understanding anyway)

My goal is to get the path of the recycling bin automatically so I don't have to dig through the registry to get it. Alternatively you can manually get this path by going to `C:\$Recycle.Bin\Recycle Bin` and the explorer path bar will then change to the key.

The key in my case appears as `S-1-5-21-3905818072-3397350780-xxxxxxxxxx-1001`

Comment: What do you need this references for?

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the sub-keys using GetSubKeyNames https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"))
{
    foreach (var subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
    }
}
```